# How can I get the percentage between two subcolumn on pandas Multinindex?

Tags: pandas, percentage, multi-index

I have this,

```
       col1     col2    
       no yes   no yes
index                  
A       2   8    2   6
B       0   2    1   1
```

I would like the percent of yes column, as follows,

```
        col1  col2    
        yes   yes
col0                  
A       0.8    0.75
B       1.0    0.5
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `axis` and `level` parameters within the arithmetic methods.

```
df.div(df.sum(axis=1, level=0), axis=1, level=0)

  col1       col2      
    no  yes    no   yes
A  0.2  0.8  0.25  0.75
B  0.0  1.0  0.50  0.50
```

---

```
df.div(df.sum(axis=1, level=0), axis=1, level=0).loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'yes']]

  col1  col2
   yes   yes
A  0.8  0.75
B  1.0  0.50
```

---

**Variations**

```
df.div(df.sum(axis=1, level=0), axis=1, level=0).xs('yes', axis=1, level=1)

  col1  col2
   yes   yes
A  0.8  0.75
B  1.0  0.50
```

---

Remove second level

```
df.div(df.sum(axis=1, level=0), axis=1, level=0).xs('yes', axis=1, level=1)

   col1  col2
A   0.8  0.75
B   1.0  0.50
```

---

Abbreviated version

```
df.div(df.sum(1, level=0), 1, 0).xs('yes', 1, 1)

   col1  col2
A   0.8  0.75
B   1.0  0.50
```

**Details**

```
df.sum(axis=1, level=0)

   col1  col2
A    10     8
B     2     2
```

We can then point `div` where to use this result

```
df.div(df.sum(axis=1, level=0), axis=1, level=0)

  col1       col2      
    no  yes    no   yes
A  0.2  0.8  0.25  0.75
B  0.0  1.0  0.50  0.50
```

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[2, 8, 2, 6], [0, 2, 1, 1]],
    list('AB'),
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['col1', 'col2'], ['no', 'yes']])
)
```